# Accessing RigidBody2d from OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider)

Tags: unity, events

I have the following script on my water object which, when the Players ship triggers it, the ships gravity is inverted to give the sense of buoyancy. I have added a 'print' statement to prove that the collision is working and that the Name condition check works, which it does. However it throws an error when trying to access the plays ship Rigidbody2D property to then access the GravityScale with the message:

*There is no 'Rigidbody2D' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Rigidbody2D to the game object "Player"...*

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        print("Player Hit Water");
        Rigidbody2D tmp = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        tmp.gravityScale *= -1;
    }
}
```

**Update:** It turns out this code is fine it was the structure of my gameobjects  that was the problem as the Rigidbody2D was in the child object, not the parent. See comments below for details.

Comment: The player ship does have a Rigedbody2D component attached btw.

Comment: what's wrong?! it work correctly

Comment: @smkplus It works for you?? For me when the event fires I get the message as shown in my OP saying there is no rigidbody2d! What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: @smkplus Turns out there was nothing wrong with my code (your suggestions also worked). The problem was my Rigidbody was on a gameobject, within my player game object. I recreated the components in my top level player object, deleted the lower level object and it works. Out of interest, if I have 2 levels of game object how would you access the lower level?

Comment: sorry i don't understand your mind.what's mean top level and lower level and how you could fix it by deleting the lower level object.if top level mean parent and lower level mean child? or level1 & level2

Comment: Yes I mean Parent and Child. Confusingly both my parent and child object were called 'Player'. It was the Child that contained the Rigidbody2D component, which is why i was getting the error message above. I therefore moved (well recreated) the rigidbody2d in the parent and then deleted the child. Then it worked. So my question now is how would you address the child object if needed? Would I do soemthing like double gameobject like this: `coll.gameObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`

Comment: `coll.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`  or `coll.gameObject.transform.FindChild("childname").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`

Comment: Of course index into it. Thanks very much. Im not new to C# but am new to Unity so still trying to learn all the structures of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use cast

```
Rigidbody2D tmp = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() as Rigidbody2D;
```

or

```
Rigidbody2D tmp = (Rigidbody2D)coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

but if don't work try this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        print("Player Hit Water");
        GameObject tmp = coll.gameObject;
        tmp.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale *= -1;
    }
}
```